# Does the Snow Queen quest end the game

Tags: smt-persona

in Shin Megami Tensei: Persona you have access to the Snow Queen Quest but does it end the game with a alternate ending or can you complete the Snow Queen Quest and continue continue after Kandori

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apparently it ends the game from a walk though i found on the long weekend, but the ending seems to tie in with the events of the regular game, i didn't read too much into it